# How can I make a libgdx sprite with texture be created at the same time as a box2d body?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

I've been working on this problem for a while, and decided to ask for help on this one.

Summary:

 I have a `bullet` class that extends `Actor`, and has a `makeBullet` method that makes a `box2d` body and fixture.

 In the draw method of my `bullet` class, I have an *if/else* statement that checks if my `shootButton` is pressed, and if it is, calls the `makeBullet` method, makes a new `Sprite` with a texture, sets the position to the `box2d` bullet, and applies a linear impulse to my bullet.

Problem:

The sprite's texture only appears when I press the `shootButton` and only right next to the player, but `box2d` bullets seem to work just fine. How can I attach an image to each of the bullets?

Sorry if I'm not very clear, I'd be very happy to explain in further detail or give more code.

`bullet` class:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

import static com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

public class bullet extends Actor{
    static BodyDef bodyDef;
    static Body body;
    static FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    static PolygonShape groundBox;
    Sprite bulletThing;

    //method that makes box2d bullet bodies, takes world and direction from main class, MyGdxGame
    public static void makeBullet(World world, int direction) {
        //makes body def
        bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = DynamicBody;
        // sets bullet at player (MyActor)'s location
        bodyDef.position.set(MyActor.body.getPosition().x, MyActor.body.getPosition().y);
        // put body in the world
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        // makes fixture for bullet body
        fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        groundBox = new PolygonShape();
        fixtureDef.shape = groundBox;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.9f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.6f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.1f; 
        groundBox.setAsBox(1f, 1f);
        // attach fixture to body
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        if (MyGdxGame.shootButton.isPressed()) {  // if my shootButton is pressed
            //makes a bullet, takes the direction from main class
            bullet.makeBullet(MyGdxGame.world, MyGdxGame.direction);
            // makes texture for sprite
            Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
            pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            pixmap.fill();
            bulletThing = new Sprite(new Texture(pixmap));
            // sets sprite texture to box2d bullet, supposedly
            bulletThing.setBounds(bullet.body.getPosition().x - bulletThing.getWidth()/2, bullet.body.getPosition().y - bulletThing.getHeight()/2, 4f, 4f);
            bulletThing.setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * bullet.body.getAngle());
            bulletThing.setOriginCenter();
            bulletThing.draw(batch);
            //fires the bullet
            body.applyLinearImpulse(MyGdxGame.direction * 1f,0,body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y, true);
        }        
    }       
}
```

main class available if requested. Thanks ahead for the help.

Comment: I am not sure what you want the end result to be but it seems bit strange that you only draw the bullet sprite when the shoot button is pressed. from your text it sounds like you want to "spawn" a bullet when the button is pressed and then continuously draw that bullet? The way I usually do it is using and entity system where each entity has a update(delta) method and in that method you set the sprites position to the bodys position

Comment: @Korpen        That's a smart way to do it. I'll look into that.